# Changing the beta tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking through questions tagged with "beta" on the main site recently. I found a large split in its usage; the majority of questions referred to the beta distribution. On the other hand, a sizable minority of questions referred to variable named beta in different contexts (for example, in a linear regression context). The existing tag excerpt referred to the beta distribution, so I removed the tag from non-beta distribution related questions. Examples of questions previously tagged as beta included:

[What does $\beta$ tell us in linear regression analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27417/what-does-beta-tell-us-in-linear-regression-analysis)

[Is a larger beta weight a better predictor than a high t-statistic?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52385/is-a-larger-beta-weight-a-better-predictor-than-a-high-t-statistic)

[Estimate of parameter $\beta$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47092/estimate-of-parameter-beta)

It seems that users may tag questions non-beta distribution related questions with "beta" again due to its ambiguous name. Based on the fact that the current tag deals with questions related to the beta distribution, I would like to suggest that the tag name be changed to beta-distribution.

This tag would fit in nicely with other distribution specific tags such as "normal-distribution" and "gamma-distribution". With its present name, there is a chance of a redundant tag due to mixing of question matter. What do other users think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1, I think this is a good idea that will help to enforce proper usage of the tag.  However, I'm not sure that tag names can be edited.  What may need to occur is to create a new tag `[beta-distribution]` and then make `[beta]` a synonym of it.

On a somewhat related note, it's worth pointing out that we do have two relevant tags for *beta-as-coefficient*: [regression-coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression-coefficients), and [predictor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predictor).

Comment: It is unfortunate that the tag name cannot be changed, but I think your proposed solution is good. The only doubt I have is that if people do use the "beta" tag incorrectly, it will be automatically changed to "beta-distribution"; is that correct?

Comment: That's right. You'd want to be sure you've re-tagged all the improperly tagged threads first.

Comment: I have made sure of that by looking through all questions. After the synonym is approved, will people be able to use "beta" any more?

Comment: I found (and changed) one question using [tag:beta] to refer to standardized regression coefficients. I created the [tag:beta-distribution] and made it the target of [tag:beta]. Now, anyone attempting to tag a thread with [tag:beta] will automatically see [tag:beta-distribution] appear (and all the links I placed here will be directed *solely* to the beta distribution tag).